# 'case' in linux zsh shell with ';;&' : parse error near `&'

Tags: linux, zsh

This example is given in the linux book which I'm following to show multiple outputs if the input matches multiple cases. The book is using bash shell but I'm using zsh shell.

```
#! /bin/zsh

# testing the 'case' syntax of zsh

read \?"enter a character: " 

case "$REPLY" in
 
    [[:upper:]])    echo "The input is an uppercase letter.";;&
    [[:lower:]])    echo "The input is a lowercase letter.";;&
    [[:alpha:]])    echo "The input is an alphanumeric letter.";;&
    *)              echo "Input is invalid.";;&
esac
```

The output should be both the alphanumeric case and lowercase letter.
but what the error showing is:

```
enter a character : f
/home/user/bin/case_testing.sh:9: parse error near `&'
```

Can anyone kindly provide the solution?

Comment: `;;&` is not a valid list terminator in `zsh`.

Comment: @chepner It [is in bash](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs), though; so, the question is, what is the closest equivalent in zsh?

Comment: thanks, I tried it just now but still the same result :(

Comment: `[[:alpha:]]` tests if a letter is alphabetic, not alphanumeric. Use `[[:alnum:]]` instead.

Comment: @chepner I tried this first with `[[:alnum:]]`, and that parsing error was showing up. Then corrected with the answer you provided both with `[[:alnum:]]` and `[[:alpha:]]` but now the "invalid input" is showing up along with the correct answers though the parsing error is gone now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash`, `;;&` causes the `case` statement to test the next pattern instead of exiting the `case` statement.

In `zsh`, the corresponding terminator is `;|`.

Both `bash` and `zsh` use `;;` to terminate the `case` statement ad `;&` to execute the list associated with the next pattern, whether or not that pattern actually matches.

The final `case` statement should look like this:

```
case "$REPLY" in

    [[:upper:]])    echo "The input is an uppercase letter." ;|
    [[:lower:]])    echo "The input is a lowercase letter." ;|
    [[:alnum:]])    echo "The input is an alphanumeric letter." ;;
    *)              echo "Input is invalid." ;;
esac
```

Whether or not `upper` or `lower` match, `alnum` could match. But if `alnum` succeeds, you don't want to move on to `*`, so use the regular `;;` terminator.

```
~ % zsh tmp.sh <<< f
The input is a lowercase letter.
The input is an alphanumeric letter.
~ % zsh tmp.sh <<< F
The input is an uppercase letter.
The input is an alphanumeric letter.
~ % zsh tmp.sh <<< 3
The input is an alphanumeric letter.
~ % zsh tmp.sh <<< "#"
Input is invalid.
```

Comment: thanks @chepner, used `;|` with the code but the result is showing the invalid answer output along with correct ones :(

Comment: On which line you are inserting `;|`?

Comment: @LinuxGeek I'm replacing all `;;&` with `;|`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, the problem is now solved :D.